# matchAll: how to replace only first 3 matchs over 4

Tags: javascript, regex

This code generates errors and I want to replace only first 3 over 4 match

https://jsfiddle.net/9Lfj0dva/

```
let test = ". . . .";
const regex = /\./gm;
let matchAll = test.matchAll(regex);
console.log(Array.from(matchAll).length);
const replacements = [1, 2, 3];
test = test.replace(regex, () => replacements.next().value);
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
let test = ". . . .";
const regex = /\./m;
const replacements = [1, 2, 3];
replacements.forEach((replacement) => test = test.replace(regex, replacement));
console.log(test);
```

I remove the global flag from the regular expression to only replace the first match found, and then loop through the replacements array.

Answer (score 1):

**1)**
You can initialize the couter to `0` and then replace it with replacement array data until `index < length - 1`

```js
let test = ". . . .";
const regex = /\./gm;
let matchAll = [...test.matchAll(regex)];

const replacements = [1, 2, 3];
let index = 0;
const length = matchAll.length;

const result = test.replace(regex, (match) => index < length - 1 ? replacements[index++] : match );
console.log(result);
```

**2)** If you want to generalise it then you can add one more condition `index < replacements.length`

```js
let test = ". . . . . .";
const regex = /\./gm;
let matchAll = [...test.matchAll(regex)];
const length = matchAll.length;
const replacements = [1, 2, 3];
let index = 0;
const result = test.replace(regex, (match) =>
  index < length - 1 && index < replacements.length
    ? replacements[index++]
    : match
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This will not get the desire result when test contains more then 4 chars

Comment: That's because you have specified *replace only first 3 matchs over 4*